# How do I do this regular expression without lookbehind (react native)

Tags: regex, react-native

It seems like when I add lookbehinds in my code, it fails to build

Sample strings:

```
 5. GET ME
 5 GET ME
 DONT GET ME
```

I want to get GET ME by making sure there is a 5 or 5. before it. Afterwards I'm expecting capitals, spaces, numbers and dashes.

With lookbehinds I'm using this:

```
/(?<=^5\. |^5 )[A-Z \d\-]+$/g
```

How can I do this without lookbehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match a 5 with an optional dot, and then capture in a group what follows.

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
^5\.?\s+([A-Z\d-]+(?:\s[A-Z\d-]+)*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV7TRY/1)